# Need help with integration $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-az}\cdot e^{-bx}\cdot dx$

Tags: integration

Need help with the following problem:

$$\int_1^{\infty}x^{-az}\cdot e^{-bx}\cdot dx$$

Where $ z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ a>0, b>0 $

I thought of turning this into:

$$\int_1^{\infty}e^{-az\log(x)}\cdot e^{-bx}\cdot dx$$
$$=\int_1^{\infty}e^{-az\log(x)-bx}\cdot dx$$
$$=\int_1^{\infty}e^{f(x)}\cdot dx$$
$$=\frac{e^{f(x)}}{f’(x)} |_1^{\infty}$$

But I am not sure if this makes sense for non-linear $f(x)$

Comment: This can be written in terms of the incomplete gamma function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: Is there any sense to use $az $ instead of  $z $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the substitution $u=bx$ transforms the integral into
$$b^{az-1}\int_b^\infty u^{-az}e^{-u}du=b^{az-1}\Gamma(1-az, b)$$